# WPF - How to finding the tab a control is on

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm very new to WPF and don't know how to do this. I have a text box in a tab item on a tab control. How can I programmatically (C#) determine what tab item is the parent of this text box? I would also like to determine what tab control is the parent of the tab item.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[TabItem.Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.parent.aspx) will provide the logical parent element of the `TabItem`; which will be the associated `TabControl`. You can use the same approach for any control with the `TabItem`.

```
((FrameworkElement)myTextBox.Parent).Parent;
```

If the item is deeper in the tree and becomes unknown in its depth you will need to begin to approach it in a recursive manner.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FrameworkElement.Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.parent.aspx) to walk up the hierarchy of a control in WPF.  This should let you (recursively) walk up until you find the TabItem, then walk up to the TabControl from there.

Answer (score 1):

I am newbie in WPF too, but what about cycle searching?
For example:

```
TextBox TB = new TextBox();
TabControl MyTabControl = new TabControl();
// ...
foreach (TabItem ti in MyTabControl.Items)
   if (TB.Parent == ti)
   {
      // textbox is here!
      MessageBox.Show(ti.ToString());
      break;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic method for finding parent controls: [How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls/636456#636456)

You can call it like this:

```
TabItem owner = UIHelper.FindVisualParent<TabItem>(myTextBox);
```